# How to Get Cart Data in NetSuite SiteBuilder Application

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am new in NetSuite Development.

I want to fetch list of product which are added in the cart to show Short Summary in Header Section. Like Item thumbnail, qty, and price.

Can anyone help me how to do this, or what I need to read to accomplish this task.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is create an SSP application and pull the cart as a JSON object from a cart.ss url.

I know the old reference checkout had a /services/cart.ss file that could be used for this (free bundle from Netsuite)

You may be able to get away with a really simple script for that:

/*ssp root url*/services/cart.ss

```
service(request, response){
    var session = nlapiGetWebContainer().getShoppingSession();
    var orderObj = session.getOrder();
    response.setContentType('JSON');
    response.writeLine(JSON.stringify({order: orderObj.getFieldValues()}));
}
```

Then when you've published the SSP application you'd access this as an root relative url from the site.

Comment: I am trying your given way. I created SSP Application link with domain and keep file .ss file like hello.ss file in SSP Application link it with my domain. But I am unable to call this file in header template section. Can you help me how to call or give any direction. : ) thanks.

Comment: This would be a client side solution. You’d make an AJAX call and format the cart with whatever client side tools work for you.